# Get a line after match found in PHP

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a text file which always contains lines like:

```
CODICE FISCALE DATA DI STAMPA

01097800625

...
...

CODICE FISCALE

FRRVCN68S14E487E <------------------------I need this line
DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA
```

I would parse the text in order to get the marked line. I tried to explode the text between "CODICE FISCALE" and "DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA" but it doesn't work.
Any suggestion?

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return '';
}
$newName     = getBetween($fileContent,'CODICE FISCALE','DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/CODICE FISCALE\n(.*?)DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA/s', $fileContent, $match);
$match[1] contains your line.
```

See a demo here: [Demo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xht-jmn)

Comment: thanks. And If I would also match the exact number of chars in the line? In the example, it is 16...

Comment: `preg_match('/CODICE FISCALE\n(.{0,16}).*?DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA/s', $fileContent, $match);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with following code by using simple [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode)

```
$file_content = file_get_contents("your_file.txt");
$file_content_separated_by_special_word = explode("\nCODICE FISCALE", $file_content);
$res = explode("\n", ltrim($file_content_separated_by_special_word[1]));
```

I have exploded with "\nCODICE FISCALE" because "CODICE FISCALE" explodes with first occurence.

You can see working demo [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ff6-a1s)

Comment: @giuseppe this actually is the most direct answer to your question. Just put "\n" in front of your $start and $end and it will work

Answer (score 1):

Though I'd prefer the other solutions, if you want to use regexes you may use

```
/^CODICE FISCALE\n([\s\S]+)DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA/m
```

[demo @ phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3Py)
[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/wL4nX8)

For example using `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all("/^CODICE FISCALE\n([\s\S]+)DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA/m", $input_lines, $output_array);
```

You may even refactor your `getBetween` function:

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){  
    preg_match_all("/^".$start."\n([\s\S]+)".$end."/m", $content, $output);
    return $output;
}
```

[working example @ phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pze-4my)

Answer (score 0):

Using [fegts](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) you can get a single from a file. You can build something like a stream parser and set a marker if the line 'DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA' was found. Then return or store the next non-empty line and reset that marker. That way you may also find those lines in files with multiple blocks ('CODICE FISCALE … DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA').

Have a look for example on [this JSON parsers source](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser/blob/master/src/JsonStreamingParser/Parser.php#L67) to get sn inspiration how to setup such a script.

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the line after some text, return null if not found.

```
function getLineAfter($file_path, $line) {
    $lines = file($file_path, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    if (($key = array_search($line, $lines)) !== false && isset($lines[$key + 1])) {
        return $lines[$key + 1];
    }
    return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
echo getLineAfter('somefile.txt', 'CODICE FISCALE');
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `explode()`, I would recommend you try using `preg_match()` (documentation can be [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).

Here is PHP code that shows it in action:

```
$string = <<<EOS
CODICE FISCALE DATA DI STAMPA

01097800625

...
...

CODICE FISCALE

FRRVCN68S14E487E
DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA
EOS;

preg_match("/\n(.*)\nDATA ASSUNZIONE DATA/", $string, $matches);
print 'I need this line: ' . $matches[1] . "\n";
```

This searches your string for a newline, followed by a bunch of text on one line, followed by a newline and then 'DATA ASSUNZIONE DATA'.  The text captured by `(.*)` is captured into the array element, `$matches[1]`.

Here is the output of the code run:

```
I need this line: FRRVCN68S14E487E
```